# Assignment to variable vs using return value immediately

Tags: c, assembly

What occurs with regards to the return value of add(a,b) in test2 in comparison to the explicit assignment to c in test?

```
void test(int a,int b) {
    int c=add(a,b);
    return incr(c);
}
void test2(int a,int b) {
    return incr(add(a,b));
}
```

Presumably assign by reference/value in the implementation of bytecode, ie for JVM, the AVM2, and Javascript interpreters/JITs is theoretically identical.

Presumably both named values (variables) and none named values are isolated instructions to a contextual place in the stack. Ie, there is no magical optimization to sling the return value into the next instruction.

Ie, the `incr` instruction in `test2` still results in `incr 3rd value of the stack` or something like that.

Comment: Depending on optimization, it may make no difference.  Its a compiler thing.   What differs between these two is not defined by C.

Comment: Check compiler generated code by yourself (release build). You'll see they're exactly the same! I'm surprised in begginers programming classes they talk about a non sense optimization instead of what is more easy to read and understand!!! :O

Comment: Do you have some believe that named temporary variables are expensive? What are the units in which you believe that expense is incurred, and why is it a cost that matters to you? Do you believe that just because a storage location has no name, that it does not exist?  The result of the `add` has to go *somewhere*; if you're not giving that location a name, it still exists.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "temporary variable". Variables always have names, and thus aren't temporary. There are temporary *values*, such as the value of the expression `add(a, b)`.

Comment: CS104(C), AP classes just talk about the theoretical implementation of pointers, array memory access, the, char arrays vs inertia. I don't know if it's expensive. It was just always a question I had because I don't know assembly. I am curious as to the behavior with regards to: assign by value and with regards to pointers for native code (assign by reference in the JVM, the AVM2, and Javascript interpreters/JITs).

Comment: Eric, I appreciate your answer. I am aware that the cost is in the order of nanoseconds, but I am curious as to the theoretical cost vs inertia. I don't understand whether you are stating that there is in fact no cost in having a name to a value. Thus,presumably both named values (variables) and none named values are instructions to a contextual place in the stack? Ie, the `incr` instruction in `test2` still results in `incr 3rd value of the stack` or something like that.

Comment: @MetaChrome: Do you think the CPU cares whether you gave a name to that storage location or not?

Comment: @KerrekSB: OK, "temporary value" then if you like. The value has to be stored somewhere. I'm in the habit of referring to the storage location associated with a value as a variable because **it's a storage location whose value can change**. What you call it is not particularly germane to my point.

Comment: @EricLippert: Sure, what I call it doesn't matter, but the standard defines it as something that's declared and has a name, so I figured it would help others to keep their head clear about C++ if the little details are right. An experienced programmer may well be sloppy about this, but that's not the primary audience here :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: I take your point. But unfortunately the C/C++ standard has chosen the jargon-ese "lvalue" to mean an expression which identifies a storage location, and that jargon impedes communication with people who haven't read the standard. Which of course does not take away from your earlier point: the temporary value is *not* an *lvalue*. You ought not to take its address, for exmaple. And therefore you are correct that I should not have described it as a variable in either the strict or relaxed sense.  Regardless though, my point remains that the value has to go *somewhere*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "it depends". On the compiler you're using, and on the options you're using with the compiler (compile for best debuggability versus for best performance).

A decent modern compiler in optimizing mode will realize that variable `c` is only being used once, immediately, in the `return` statement and will just leave the value on the top of the stack so it can be `return`ed.

In debugging mode, that optimization is usually turned off and the value is assigned to a real variable named `c`, occupying a slot in the stack frame. This lets you pause after that line and examine the value, to see what was assigned to it, before the return executes. It costs a few more cycles, but since this is not the mode you normally use for code shipped to "customers" or for performance analysis that usually doesn't matter to anyone except the compiler/debugger authors.